# want to perform something untill button is pressed Android

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

In android,
for example 
i want to perform a text.settext("something dynamic") until the buTTon is pressed. how to do it?

Comment: [a Thread for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: `until` or `while` the buTTon is pressed? Please explain step by step behavior.

Comment: Sorry,
while the buTTon is pressed. 

like i have a function returndate() which return date and current time, and i want to show output of this function dynamically until i do not press the buTTon

Comment: what when you press the button? please mention full behavior 
1) before button press,2) during button press,3) after button pressed

Comment: kk when you press button then print current date and after press release then print date+current time?

Comment: When i press the buTTon then there should not be no more update in <text>
if the button is not pressed yet then update should be there again and again

Comment: i can't understand clearly what you are telling please can you tell me in HINDI what you want do?  @AnkitPulkit

Comment: Main ye chahta hu ki...
koi function hai jo current time and date return kar rha hai -returndate() aur ek mere pass textview text hai , aur ek button buTTon hai.... 

jab tak main button ko press nhi karu... tab tak har second me.. time and date update hote rhe "text:" me.... jab click krdu buTTon pe to ye process band ho jaye... for example

while(!buTTon.clicked)
{
text.settext("Current Date and Time :"+returndate());
}

is type ka scenario chahiye..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
android.os.Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable rUpdateTextView = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        yourTextView.setText(returndate());
        // Update your TextView every 200ms
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    mHandler.post(rUpdateTextView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(rUpdateTextView);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //click event for your button   
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String time = returndate();

            //set your text to textView
            test.setText(time);
        }
    });
}
```